# How to hide/unhide lines based on tags in TCL/TK

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a set of lines create and displayed on a canvas :

```
.can create line 100 200 300 400 -fill red -tag red
.can create line 1000 200 1300 400 -fill green -tag green
.can create line 500 300 800 400 -fill blue -tag blue
.can create line 1100 200 3020 1400 -fill red -tag red
```

I would like to have checkboxes/seperate buttons for each color through which i can control lines of which color should be displayed. 
eg : If only red and blue checkboxes are checked, then display red and blue and hide green lines.

Can i achieve this functionality using tags together with bind actions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is easy to achieve with the canvas. You can set the state of an object or collection of objects (via tags) to "hidden" to make the items invisible, or "normal" to make them visible again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the following code can be used to hide and show items with the tag "lineTag".

```
.canvas itemconfigure lineTag -state hidden
.canvas itemconfigure lineTag -state normal
```

Simply bind a checkbutton to issue these commands to accomplish what you asked.

```
.canvas add checkbutton -label "Red Lines" -variable ::MyNameSpace::show_red_lines -command ::MyNameSpace::HideOrShowRed

proc ::MyNameSpace::HideOrShowRed { } {
    if { $::MyNameSpace::show_red_lines } {
        .canvas itemconfigure redLineTag -state normal
    } else {
        .canvas itemconfigure redLineTag -state hidden
    }
}
```